# How to add internationalization to Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, internationalization, spring-bean

I am trying to use add Internationalization to my Spring based project. I tried a lot of guides but I can't make it work. I am stuck at this for a long time and I can't find whats wrong.So to start, my `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml` looks like this:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.application" />

    <!-- Bean for the static resources (css,js) -->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
        in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>


    <!--Internationalization -->
    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />

    </bean>

    <mvc:interceptors>
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
            <property name="paramName" value="language" />
        </bean>
    </mvc:interceptors>
</beans>
```

My `messages_en.properties` file contains:

```
label.firstName=First Name
label.lastName=Last Name
```

Also on my JSP i used the placeholder: `<spring:message code="label.firstName" />`
and this is my project structure: 
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:
Thanks to souser comment, I found out that the resources folder with the internationalization messages is not on the deployed war (on tomcat). The only resources folder present it's the one with static resources(/WebContent/resources/ from the screenshoted project structure)

Comment: It should work, I have something similar. Did you clean your project?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I cleaned my project redeployed, but it stil don't work.

Comment: In case you are using Tomcat, can you see the messages file in the exploded WAR in the webapps directory ?

Comment: @souser I looked on the exploded WAR, and the resources package with my messages file it's not indeed there. There is only one resources folder, the one with static resources.(/WebContent/resources/ from the picture). I tried to put my message file on the resources folder that is present(static resources one), the message file are now on the war, but the internationalization still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that messages_en.properties is not getting to your classpath upon launch. Check project properties->build path and check to see how resources is being handled. Are there any exclusion filters? Also, generally, I turn all projects into maven projects in Eclipse. Not a direct answer to your question, but it's something you should start doing.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help! I checked the build path and there is no exclusion filters, all files are included.Also about maven, i have to use ant for this project to create and deploy my project.